# What is the proper way to include resources on multiple Forms in an app?

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

I have an application with an existing Form that has images on each ToolStripButton at the top. These images are in the `resx` file and look as though they are only available to this Form. I want to make another Form with the same images.

What is the proper way to import these images so that all my Forms can use them. For example, the Save and Open buttons will be on most of the Forms.

Comment: Not exactly what you were asking for but an MDI construct with parent and child forms may be better suited for your scenario. That way you have only one instance of the toolstripitem and execute items based in selected childform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a big project at work we have a solution that has many projects with user controls and forms. That is why we have one extra project called Resources that holds different kind of resources (separate resource files) for the whole solution:

- strings (translations)
- images
- property names
- and so on

We reference the project to every other project in the solution where a resource is needed. This way the resources are kept separately, the dll can be easily replaced and nothing will be broken, as long the same resource names are used.

We also use the dll assembly in complete different projects(solutions) where we need for example the same images. When named correctly (for example Company.Resources.dll -> Company.Resources.Images.Toolbar.Add/Remove/Settings) it fits very well into every new project.

In your case it is of cource possible to reference ProjectA in ProjectB in order to use the same resources (as long the projects are in the same solution), but it could be that this will be not always possible (for example in order to avoid circular references).

---

Create new WinForm solution (in my example one solution with two projects). Add new project of type **Class Library**:

[image: Adding resources project]

Add new resources to the *resources* project (in my example for strings and images):

[image: adding resources to the resources project]

[image: add resources project resource]

[image: add texts]

Adding a resource file for images:

[image: add images resources]

Add some images:

[image: adding images to the images resource file]

[image: adding images to the file]

Now reference the resources project from the other projects:

[image: reference the resources project]

[image: reference resources project]

**Important** => In order to use the resources from outside the assembly, you need to set the visibility to public:

[image: set resources visibility]

Compile the solution once and use the references resources project from everywhere:

[image: resources project usage]

Comment: Can you post some code or explain how to use the Windows Forms Designer to add those resources?

Comment: Beautiful! I was able to find a Resources.resx file in the Properties directory and that solved my problem. But this will be very helpful for new projects. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that the answer was helpful.